# How to attach column from one file to another file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How can I attach the first column of a file to another file, using UNIX commands, etc.?

Example:

```
file1
-----
10 foo
20x bar
30 baz

file2
-----
obama
clinton 
nixon

Result:
-------
10 obama
20x clinton
30 nixon
```

In my case, `file1` and `file2` are guaranteed to have the same numbers of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut` and `paste`:

```
paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file1) file2
```

Output:

```
$ paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file1) file2
10 obama
20x clinton 
30 nixon
```

Comment: You can also do `cut -d' ' -f1 in1 | paste -d' ' - in2`